# Saving Data (OnSaveInstanceState)

Tags: xamarin.android

I just started to develop with this program. I did some research about saving the data between activities, and my doubt is. If my application becomes too complex i think it's impracticable to use OnSaveInstanceState because of his statement. Example:

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            // Save the values you need from your textview into "outState"-object
            outState.PutInt("var1" 1);
            outState.PutInt("var2" 2);
            outState.PutInt("varn" n);
        }
```

So, if i have 100 variables, i need to declare to 100 variables (and restore them in OnCreate) ? There's any simple way to do that ? This works with objects too ?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

For long lists of similar variables, there are array Put methods - e.g. PutIntArray

For objects you can always use a serialisation technique - e.g. xml or JSON - and can then save the string

To assist with this, Android provides Parcelable to assist with this mechanism: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Personally, I'd use JSON.Net and PutString to store serialized objects.